# Newbie git: difficulties on remote branch workflow

Tags: git

I'm having difficulty trying to work with a remote git branch:

There are two branches: **master** and **Devel**. We intend to maintain a **master** practically untouched, so we work on the **Devel**.

On the server I created the branch **Devel**, and when I go to work with it, I clone:

```sh
clone git / 10.0.0.100/project --branch Devel
```

In the local repo I work normally executing **commits** referring to what I am doing:

```sh
git add.
git commit -m "Test changes"
```

At the end, I push the branch to the server:

```sh
git push origin Devel
```

Then, when I clone it in another folder (even in another machine), none of the changes comes.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: You need to be on the Devel branch to see the changes `git checkout Devel`

Comment: @WebGerente when you did `git push` did you --set-upstream branch?

Comment: @ArunG I've did the push without any flags, just `git push origin Devel`

Comment: @LakshayGarg I did it, when I push the changes to my server i get the return `Everything up-to-date`, I'm 100% sure that I'm on Devel branch, but when I clone this same branch in any other machine, I just can't see the last push changes...

Answer (score 2):

If you simply cloned, you would likely get the master branch's contents in your working directory. Try checking out the `Devel` branch to see the changes.

```
# Do this after cloning
git checkout Devel
```

Comment: I already did that:

`$ git status`
`On branch Devel`
`nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: @WebGerente, Please show the output of `git status` before and after each command and `git branch` as well as `git commit` on the original machine.

Comment: Thanks for the attention! `git status` return `On branch Devel nothing to commit, working tree clean` the returno for `git branch` is `* Devel`  `master` and the return for `git commit` is `On branch Devel` `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

Comment: @WebGerente, Does `git log` on your original clone show the commit?

Comment: the `git log` doen't showed my last commit, so I redo all the steps, and this time I used the git GUI to stage and commit the changes, after that I pull the changes and everything worked smooth, thanks for your help!